# Django redundant user relation in related models for permission purposes

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

I am pretty new to django and backend, I made two models `Car & Service` which have a relation to user (to check permissions, while operating on them) and now I am trying to relate one with another, I have noticed they have both user relation, but Service can't exists without Car, so I start wondering if there is any sense of having user relation in Service just for permissions puroposes, or is it better to create separete permissions for every Model:

Car Model:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

and Service Mode:

```
class Service(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    car = models.ForeignKey(
        "cars.Car",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="services",
    )
```

and permission used in both API views for those models:

```
class isAuthorOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True
        return obj.user == request.user
```

What would be your advice in this scenario ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more design than a technical question. If in your app `Service` cannot exist without a `Car`, then the `Service.user` attribute is redundant. Then you can rewrite your permission check to something like this:

```py
class isAuthorOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True
        elif isinstance(obj, Car):
            return obj.user == request.user
        elif isinstance(obj, Service):
            return obj.car.user == request.user
```